# Determine slope given one point and y-intercept.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The graph of the relation y = mx + 35 passes through the point (8,–77). Determine the value Of m.

I understand how to find the y intercept when given slope and a point, but i can't seem to find the slope given the graph of the relation and one point.

This is how i initially tried to solve the question:

Y-intercept= 35

Point (8, -77)
-77 = mx (8) + 35

-77 = mx (8) + 35

8mx + 35 = -77

8mx + 35 + - 35 = -77 + -35

8mx= - 112

8 mx / 8x = -112 / 8x

M = -14 / x

Comment: What is the value of $x$ when $y$ is equal to the y-intercept?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If the line passes through the point $(8,-77)$ this means that the coordinates $x=8$ and $y=-77$ verifies the equation $ y=mx +35$, so you have:
$$
-77=8m+35
$$
now solve for $m$ and you have the slope.

Answer (score 0):

Just plug the given point into the equation, getting$-77=8m+35$ and solve.

Answer (score 0):

Given 2 points, can you find the slope?

[image]

hint:
$$\text{slope} = m = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$